# Converting and formatting non standard String to Integer in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Problem:**
Value in field 'Savings' is a string, which has allowed users to input a variety of string formats. See example, specifically the bold formatted values.

Note: option to convert 'Savings' field to an integer in the database/input field not available currently, as this would be the ideal solution.

| Savings |
| --- |
| 500 |
| 60 |
| 5days |
| 12 |
| **NULL** |
| **$100K** |
| 10 |
| **60.5** |
| 0 |
| **$50thousand** |
| **1M** |

**Expected Results/Output:**
Transform current string values and output integer type value ideally in thousands (K) to allow summation of standard integer type values.

i.e. 300 = 300K

| Savings (K) |
| --- |
| 500 |
| 60 |
| 0 |
| 12 |
| **0** |
| **100** |
| 10 |
| **61** |
| 0 |
| **50** |
| **1000** |

**Current Query:** Query works 90% however it cannot

1. round floats i.e. 60.5 to 61
2. set strings that contain 'days' = 0

```
    SELECT 
             [Savings] 
             ,LEFT(SUBSTRING([Savings], PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', [Savings]), 8000),
               PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING([Savings], PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', [Savings]), 8000) 
               + 'X') -1) AS cleaned_savings
           
      FROM tbl
```

Comment: AFAIK, floats don't have corners. How do you want [round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) floats? Up, down, banker's, ...? How do you want to handle separators, e.g. `1,024.00` or `1.000.000,00`?

Comment: floats can be rounded up. separators can be comma e.g. 1,024

Comment: If you're changing from `Savings` to `Savings (K)` then shouldn't `500` become `0.5`, etc.? Integer doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: 500 (500,000.00) should be represented as 500 in the output in this case.

Comment: @aaron_ca anything you try will be an ugly hack. None of these strings is in any way "standard", not even for the US. You'd have serious trouble parsing these with a regular expression, which SQL Server doesn't have anyway. Using wildcards like you try to do would require a *very* complex and error prone expression. T-SQL is simply not suitable for text manipulation. It would be far easier to parse the data on the client or create a SQLCLR function using eg regular expressions to split and parse the text

Comment: @aaron_ca another option would be to write a SQL Server function that parses the string. It will still be a lot harder than using C#, but at least it will be easier to write, test and fix. You'll be able to use conditional logic and splitting, which can't fit into a single expression. The performance of that expression will be bad one way or another, so using a multi-statement function won't be any worse

Comment: thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I understand it wont be pretty, and much more akin to a hack. However this is just a temporary solution until the user input/table can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the non-digits, you can use a trick using `translate()` (which is a relatively recent addition to SQL Server):

```
select t.savings, replace(translate(t.savings, v.nondigits, replicate('x', len(v.nondigits))), 'x', '')
from (values ('$50thousand'), ('$100K'), (NULL), ('500')) t(savings) cross apply
     (values (translate(savings, '0123456789', 'xxxxxxxxxx'))) v(nondigits);
```

The idea is to replace the digits you want to keep in the string with something else -- in this case `'x'`.  Then use the result as a new `translate()` string.  SQL Server doesn't care that characters appear multiple times in the string.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee29d04a27814d4f83c1d4a835920e80) is a db<>fiddle.